# Difference between lua and env lua?

Tags: linux, lua

Is there any difference between starting a program file with any of those?

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua
#!/usr/bin/lua
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/lua
```

This specifies that the only Lua allowed to run is the one in `/usr/bin`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua
```

This runs the Lua that the user would have gotten from the `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Doesn't `#!/usr/bin/env foo` have security implications if the script has different permissions than the user?